# MVC Controller enable disable controls

Tags: c++, model-view-controller, design-patterns

In my application which is in c++ I am using the MVC Pattern. I have a lot of model objects, and a list of actions that could be taken to them from the ui. But the actions can be done only if some conditions are met :

- I can't show objectA if objectB is shown or objectC is shown,
- and can't do any actions on objectA if it is not shown
- other more complex conditions

So I was thinking to have class which will validate if objects of particular class has valid actions at the moment :

```
AActionValidator
{ 
 bool CanDoX();
 bool CanDoY();        

};
BActionValidator
{
  bool CanDoZ();
};
```

The Controllers classes will ask this ActionValidators if some operation is availbale at particular moment, and if yes they will do the operation.

Concern 1 :
But how to disable/enable the ui controls automatically when some action becomes available/unavailable ? I guess these ActionValidators classes should also emit some event when this happens? But then my ui controls should connect to events of bunch different ActionValidator classes

Concern 2:
Maybe it is better to have one global ApplicationActionManager class which emits the events, and stores information about valid actions for all objects across the application ? But I am afraid that it will become one big non-coherent class eventually

Concern 3:
When ObjectA is Shown,  the controller can also set the Show button to disabled and enable the Hide button, because this is simple case, but is this the job of the controller to update control state  ? Or I should emit the the show/hidden state as event too ?

Any insights how this can be done . Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I completely understand what you're getting at here, but I'll try and offer a few pointers having done similar things with an MVC framework before.

I usually implement the validation in the model (though that's not to say it's right to do so!).  Any action you make which could alter the validity of objects needs to call the validation function from the controller after the object properties have been set which should then update the views.

Using pure virtual base classes can be useful on an object level.  For example, have a CanDoAction() pure virtual function which all your objects have to implement, then objectA can return false if it's not visible.  You can then use the model validation function to implement the dependencies between objects which should give you a kind of hierarchical validation process.

I hope that makes some kind of sense.